# Помогите с версткой, не получается контейнер сделать и картинки внутри card и у date_of_lesson добавить padding без изменения размера card

Tags: html, css

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oix-SeBvjsLMJUMyd2wS5qleFFU9dDm4
Есть контейнер с свойствами width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; Но почему-то после создания блока "cards" этот контейнер будто сдвинулся влево, не получается в блоках card сделать что бы картинка была нормального размера и у блока с информацией внутри card был padding.

Comment: код сюда надо - кому надо скачивать ваш макет ? 100% ни кто этого делать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Таки нашелся тот извращенец, скачавший макет из вопроса ;)
Макет довольно большой, оставила без изменений на [codepen](https://codepen.io/Vilyaca/pen/JjYXWLY)

Ваш "контейнер сдвинулся влево" из-за ширины 44% для блока `card`. Суммарная ширина **внутренних блоков** в одну строку составит 88%, так же не применяется ничего для выравнивания блоков `card`, поэтому появился сдвиг влево. Один из вариантов чтобы выровнять по центру, добавить следующее:

```
.programms .cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Для картинок используйте обёртку, дополнительный блок, внутри которого будет растянутая картинка:

```
<div class="card__img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1oN7mdPWnr1uHTOmZt460cJAAkSDaFfEJ=w2880-h1144-iv1">
</div>

.cards .card__img-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.cards .card__img-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения - вопрос пришлось закрыть так  как он не соответствует правилам ресурса но поставил плюсик за старания